# (pytorch) I want to normalize [0 255] integer tensor to [0 1] float tensor

Tags: python, casting, pytorch, tensor, normalize

I want to normalize [0 255] integer tensor to [0 1] float tensor.

I used cifar10 dataset and wanted to deal with integer image tensor. 
so I made them integer tensor
when I loaded dataset, I used "transforms.ToTensor()" so the values were set to [0 1] float

```
tensor([[[0.4588, 0.4588, 0.4588,  ..., 0.4980, 0.4980, 0.5020],
         [0.4706, 0.4706, 0.4706,  ..., 0.5098, 0.5098, 0.5137],
         [0.4824, 0.4824, 0.4824,  ..., 0.5216, 0.5216, 0.5294],
         ...,
         [0.3098, 0.3020, 0.2863,  ..., 0.4549, 0.3608, 0.3137],
         [0.2902, 0.2902, 0.2902,  ..., 0.4431, 0.3333, 0.3020],
         [0.2706, 0.2941, 0.2941,  ..., 0.4157, 0.3529, 0.3059]],

        [[0.7725, 0.7725, 0.7725,  ..., 0.7569, 0.7569, 0.7608],
         [0.7765, 0.7765, 0.7765,  ..., 0.7608, 0.7608, 0.7686],
         [0.7765, 0.7765, 0.7765,  ..., 0.7608, 0.7608, 0.7725],
         ...,
         [0.6510, 0.6314, 0.6078,  ..., 0.6941, 0.6510, 0.6392],
         [0.6314, 0.6235, 0.6118,  ..., 0.6784, 0.6196, 0.6275],
         [0.6157, 0.6235, 0.6157,  ..., 0.6549, 0.6431, 0.6314]],
```

To make them [0 255] integer tensor.

```
temp = np.floor(temp_images*256)
temp_int = torch.tensor(temp, dtype=torch.int32)
temp_images = torch.clamp(temp, 0, 255)
```

and the result was

```
torch.IntTensor
tensor([[[[ 94., 100., 100.,  ...,  98., 100., 102.],
          [ 86., 100., 101.,  ...,  83.,  91., 103.],
          [ 90., 100.,  99.,  ...,  80.,  66.,  86.],
          ...,
          [ 92.,  92.,  90.,  ...,  77., 107., 119.],
          [ 76.,  91., 100.,  ...,  95., 158., 170.],
          [ 86.,  83.,  87.,  ...,  97., 176., 205.]],

         [[105., 111., 111.,  ..., 109., 112., 113.],
          [ 97., 111., 112.,  ...,  94., 102., 114.],
          [101., 111., 110.,  ...,  90.,  77.,  97.],
          ...,
          [111., 110., 108.,  ...,  88., 120., 131.],
          [ 95., 108., 114.,  ..., 105., 165., 172.],
          [106., 100., 101.,  ..., 108., 183., 206.]],

         [[ 62.,  68.,  68.,  ...,  66.,  68.,  70.],
          [ 55.,  69.,  70.,  ...,  51.,  59.,  71.],
          [ 59.,  69.,  68.,  ...,  48.,  34.,  54.],
          ...,
          [ 59.,  59.,  56.,  ...,  54.,  95., 107.],
          [ 49.,  61.,  66.,  ...,  76., 152., 166.],
          [ 61.,  55.,  54.,  ...,  73., 170., 206.]]],
```

before forwarding them to the network,
I want to make them [0 1] float tensor again.

So I tried

```
transforms.Normalize((0.5,0.5,0.5),(0.5,0.5,0.5))
```

But, the result is not normalized to [0 1] and rather it becomes bigger...!

```
tensor([[[117., 117., 117.,  ..., 127., 127., 128.],
         [120., 120., 120.,  ..., 130., 130., 131.],
         [123., 123., 123.,  ..., 133., 133., 135.],
         ...,
         [ 79.,  77.,  73.,  ..., 116.,  92.,  80.],
         [ 74.,  74.,  74.,  ..., 113.,  85.,  77.],
         [ 69.,  75.,  75.,  ..., 106.,  90.,  78.]],

        [[197., 197., 197.,  ..., 193., 193., 194.],
         [198., 198., 198.,  ..., 194., 194., 196.],
         [198., 198., 198.,  ..., 194., 194., 197.],
```

to

```
tensor([[[233., 233., 233.,  ..., 253., 253., 255.],
         [239., 239., 239.,  ..., 259., 259., 261.],
         [245., 245., 245.,  ..., 265., 265., 269.],
         ...,
         [157., 153., 145.,  ..., 231., 183., 159.],
         [147., 147., 147.,  ..., 225., 169., 153.],
         [137., 149., 149.,  ..., 211., 179., 155.]],

        [[393., 393., 393.,  ..., 385., 385., 387.],
         [395., 395., 395.,  ..., 387., 387., 391.],
         [395., 395., 395.,  ..., 387., 387., 393.],
         ...,
         [331., 321., 309.,  ..., 353., 331., 325.],
         [321., 317., 311.,  ..., 345., 315., 319.],
         [313., 317., 313.,  ..., 333., 327., 321.]],
```

***How I can normalize [0 255] integer tensor to [0 1] float tensor?***

Comment: I might miss the point, but why aren't you just dividing by 255...or just don't multiply it with 255 in the first place?

Comment: @sxeros yup you are right! thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you seem to misunderstand what `transforms.Normalize` does. To quote from the [PyTorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.Normalize):

> Normalize a tensor image with mean and standard deviation. Given mean:
>   `(M1,...,Mn)` and std: `(S1,..,Sn)` for `n` channels, this transform will
>   normalize each channel of the input `torch.*Tensor` i.e. `input[channel] = (input[channel] - mean[channel]) / std[channel]`

The calculation for a value of, say `100`, and the std and mean you provided would then be: `100 - 0.5 / 0.5 = 199`.
Of course, you could increase std and mean, but this does not guarantee you the exact result that you might expect.
As suggested in the comments, the best way would probably be to invert the operations that you performed in order to get the tensor to `[0 255]` in the first place.

**Edit:**
As it turns out, according to [this forum post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-pil-to-tensor-and-vice-versa/6312/3), it seems that the transformations from PIL images to tensors automatically turn your value range to `[0 1]` (and to `[0 255]` if you transform *to* a PIL image, respectively), as is written in the fine-print of [`transforms.ToTensor`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.ToTensor). For the return transformation [it is not explicitly stated](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.ToPILImage), but can be enforced via the `mode`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I misunderstood it would be normalized to have mean 0.5 and std 0.5 if I use that function. I should have read function document more. Thank You for your answer.

Comment: No worries, this is what Stackoverflow is for ;-) In fact, I myself have not read enough in the documentation, since there seems to be an even better way to solve this! I'll update in a few minutes.